# LARAVEL queues with Storage directories

Tags: php, laravel, directory, queue, storage

I try to use the queue system of laravel 5.7 (it is the first time for me ;-)).
I builded a script which browse a folder (with a lot files and subfolders), open excel files, recover some datas in it and put all thoses datas in the mysql database.
The script is too long to execute. I want to do it in background with the queue system of laravel.
The first function in my script is this one:

```php
$directories = Storage::disk('doc')->directories();
```

When I test this line in a Controller it is working.
Or if I do that:

```php
Route::get('/test', function (){
   $directories = Storage::disk('doc')->directories();
   dd($directories);
});
```

the page displays an array with the list of directories (as expected).
But, when I try to do this in a Job (handle function):

```php
$directories = Storage::disk('doc')->directories();
print_r($directories);
```

The array displayed in the CLI is empty.
When I do that in the same Job:

```php
$file_url = Storage::disk('doc')->url('name.xlsx');
print_r($file_url);
```

The url displayed in the CLI is correct! So my disk storage is set up the right way!
Why the ->directories() function doesnt work in a Job Handle ? The ->files() function doesn't work either..!

Thank you for your help!!!!!

Comment: I doubt the permissions to the files/directories, but you can check some suggestions [here](https://laravel.io/forum/07-11-2014-file-permission-problems-in-queue-jobs) it might help.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `Storage::disk('doc')->url('name.xlsx')` doesn't actually access the filesystem to create the url, so that won't tell you anything useful about whether your disk is configured properly

Comment: Ok, understood! Thank both of you! But when I run the command "php artisan queue:work" in my local server (laragon) if I understand, this is the same user... no?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I don't know if it is the best way but it seems to work (in local):

```
$doc = Storage::disk('doc')->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
$path = public_path().'\\'.$doc;
$files = new Filesystem;
$dir = $files->directories($path);
print_r($dir);
```

The array is not empty!!!

Don't forget:

```
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
```